# UI Test Automation In .NET

Tags: c#, .net, ui-automation

I want to know how could I write a program in C# that opens a browser and go to google.com (I did that easily)

I want to write code to automate move mouse to the input text field, click the mouse and then enter some text. move mouse to search button and hit it.

I know I should deal with iAccessible interface but I did not find any useful source.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why would you do it that way instead of just Process.Start("url")? Can't think of any reason besides 'because I can' ;-)

Comment: I want to do it this way because I have a big project that I should learn how to automate every thing, to start working in it

Answer (score 3):

You can also try Winium, an automation library similar to Selenium through which you can do automated testing and instruct it to perform testing even on remote machines.  We have used it at our organization in combination with Selenium to perform automated testing of Windows and Web modules. It is free to use and open source. Here are the links.

https://github.com/2gis/Winium and https://github.com/2gis/Winium.Desktop

Answer (score 2):

Look at the Windows Automation API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms726294(VS.85).aspx

and the Test API: testapi.codeplex.com which has some related packages you'll likely need.
Sorry, can't post more than one link yet, but add the usual bits to get to the TestAPI site on codeplex.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Visual Studio Test Suite](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/sv-se/products/2010-editions/test-professional) it lets you record how you interact with your application and then lets you run it automaticly.

It's a powerful product.

Comment: Link has been removed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to understand UI Automation, I've just started that myself. I wrote this project so that other people could use it or understand themselves too:

http://code.google.com/p/wipflash/

Mostly it's based around the Patterns and Properties. You can see how I've used the Patterns here:

http://code.google.com/p/wipflash/source/browse/#hg/WiPFlash/Framework/Patterns

Hope it helps.

(Edit: I also answered a similar question here: [WPF, Project White and Infragistics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920593/3037463#3037463) - you're probably looking for the `ValuePattern`).

Answer (score 0):

There is a commercial solution that would do the job: Telerik WebUI Test Studio. It also supports Silverlight apps.

http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools.aspx

Here is one positive review:

http://fczaja.blogspot.com/2011/01/ui-tests-automation-for-silverlight.html